# Python class -- How may I access an double underscored attribute that is added through object within a method of the class

Tags: python, class

In the below program is it possible to access __breadth attribute in area(self) method?

```
class Rectangle:
    def __init__(self, L):
        self.__length = L
        
    def area(self):
        return self.__length * self.__breadth
          
b = Rectangle(10)
b.__breadth = 5
print(b.__dict__)
print(b.area())
```

I have tried to access __braedth in the area(self) method but it is not possible.

Comment: This seems like an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/223254). The obvious answer to how to avoid your trouble is "don't do that". Double-underscore prefixed names in methods get mangled. If you use a double-underscore prefixed attribute from module-level code, it doesn't get mangled, which makes it very hard for code in methods to get at the unmangled name. Do yourself a favor and just don't use double underscored names unless you really need to! If you used a single underscore, your code would work exactly as you show it.

Comment: In your case, use `b._Rectangle__breadth = 5` instead of `b.__breadth = 5`. Read the "Private name mangling" part in https://docs.python.org/3.12/reference/expressions.html#atom-identifiers for more details.

Answer (score 0):

You should never have written `b.__breadth = 5`.  The intent of double underscore is that this variable is private to the class and should never be accessed from outside it.  If you need to modify `__breadth` from outside, you should have a `set_breadth` method inside the class.

```
class Rectangle:
    ...
    def set_breadth(value):
        self.__breadth = value

b.set_breadth(5)
```

Alternatively, create a `breadth` property.  Google "Python Properties" to learn how to do this.